# jQuery count JSON by Key and Value (could this function work?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
function countJSONObjByKeyValue(obj, key, value)
{
    var countJSONShows = 0;
    $.each(obj, function(i, item)
    {
        if(obj[i].key == value){ countJSONShows++; }
    });
    alert(countJSONShows);
}
countJSONObjByKeyValue("dashboardJSON.widgets", "show", "false");
```

is it plausible to think something along the lines there of the function above could work? If so what is wrong with this current function/call to it that I could do to make it work?

I know doing it without the wrapping of a function I can do it just fine but I would like the concept to be reusable.

Comment: You're passing a string instead of an object there.

Comment: any insight how to pass it as an object then? cause even trying "dashboardJSON.widgets" without the quotes gets me a 0 count when I know theres at least 1 currently

Comment: have you tested it? i don't think obj[i].key is going to work since key is a string

Comment: try obj[i][key] instead of obj[i].key

Comment: @spacevillian, you just nailed it.. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work, however you could also do:

```
function countJSONObjByKeyValue(obj, key, value)
{
   var countJSONShows = 0;


   for(x in obj){
        if(obj[i].key == value){ countJSONShows++; }
   }
   window.alert(countJSONShows);
}
countJSONObjByKeyValue(dashboardJSON.widgets, "show", "false");
```

Also note, obj mustnt be passed as a string

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the dashboardJSON.widgets looks like, so I can't tell you 100% of what the problem is.

However, a obvious issue is the way that you are referencing the key. When dealing with JSON, you can reference the key the following two ways:

```
var o = {"foo":"bar"};
o.foo;
o["foo"];
```

What you need to do, since you are passing a String value of the key in as a param, you need to use the second way:

```
obj[i][key]
```